# aws credentials not loading on mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have already hard coded these credentials into my js files and it works:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: "...",
  secretAccessKey: "...",
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

If I delete the hard coded creds and then...
I also created a credentials file at:
/Users/todd/.aws/credentials
with the following code:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

Doesn't seem to find that file.

I also then tried to create environment variables by going into my .bash_profile file and wrote:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
```

which also does not work. Can someone point me in the right direction to get either the credentials file or environment variables to work with my js files for node, so I don't have to hard code in my key and secret on every file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the credentials hard-coded in your code like that, it will always use that. It won't look at the config file or the environment variables if you have credentials explicitly specified in your code. If you delete the `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` lines from you code then it should pick up the environment variables, followed by the default credentials file.

Note that the environment variables should **not** have `S3_` in their names. They should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

Comment: I understand the hard coding, I deleted them out before trying the other options. Good point on the S3 (careless copying), I will remove and try.

Comment: That worked. Do you know what aws checks first between credentials file and environment variables? How can I tell which one it is using?

Comment: Check the documentation here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/ the order it checks is Environment variables, credentials file, IAM role.